# Filter a list based on many parameters and gather the result in another list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list of objects. An object has the following properties:

```
public string mCardColor { get; set; }

public string mCardType { get; set; }

public string mCardRarity { get; set; }
```

In my view I have the possibility to filter directly the list obtained via a search engine using dropdownlists.

I then pass the values of the filters to the controller method and check if the request is an actual Ajax request like this:

```
public ActionResult DisplayCardsResults(string _rarity = "", string _type = "", string _color = "")
{
    ViewBag._rarity = _rarity;
    ViewBag._color = _color;
    ViewBag._type = _type;

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        mListCardColors = null;
        mListCardType = null;
        mListCardRarity = null;

        if (_rarity != "All")
        {
            mListCardRarity = mListCards.Where(_item => _item.mMasterCard.mCardRarity == _rarity).ToList();
        }
        if (_type != "All")
        {
            mListCardType =
                mListCards.Where(_item => _item.mMasterCard.mCardType.ToLower().Contains(_type.ToLower())).ToList();
        }
        if (_color != "All")
        {
            mListCardColors = mListCards.Where(_item => _item.mMasterCard.mCardColor == _color).ToList();
        }

        if (mListCardType == null && mListCardColors == null && mListCardRarity == null)
        {
            return PartialView("_ResultsTable", mListCards.ToPagedList(pageNumber, ValueDomain.PAGE_SIZE));
        }

        mListCardsToShow = new List<CardDisplay>();

        if (mListCardType != null)
        {
            mListCardsToShow.AddRange(mListCardType);
        }
        if (mListCardRarity != null)
        {
            mListCardsToShow.AddRange(mListCardRarity);
        }
        if(mListCardColors != null)
        {
            mListCardsToShow.AddRange(mListCardColors);
        }

        return PartialView("_ResultsTable", mListCardsToShow.ToPagedList(pageNumber, ValueDomain.PAGE_SIZE));
    }

    if (mListCardsToShow.Count > 0)
    {
        mListCardsToShow = SortListOrder(_sortOrder, mListCardsToShow);
        return View(mListCardsToShow.ToPagedList(pageNumber, ValueDomain.PAGE_SIZE));
    }

    if (mListCards.Count > 0)
    {
        mListCards = SortListOrder(_sortOrder, mListCards);
    }

    return View(mListCards.ToPagedList(pageNumber, ValueDomain.PAGE_SIZE));
}
```

You have 2 list: the `mListCards` is the list of cards obtained from the search engine. This does not need to change. The `mListCardsToShow` is used only if the request is an Ajax request.

I want to retain only the values wanted based on the filters passed to the controller method. The principle is the following: if the three dropdownlist are on all, show all cards. But if there's a value in any or all the dropdownlist, the actual list needs to be filtered.

Is there an efficient way to filter the list based on the three param using Linq other than to write 9 differents scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a strong reason not to, it probably makes sense to filtering on the three fields simultaneously:

```
var filteredCards =
    from card in mListCards
    where _color == "ALL" || card.mCardColor == _color
    where _type == "ALL" || card.mCardType == _type
    where _rarity == "ALL" || card.mCardRarity == _rarity
    select card;
```

Comment: But your code does the opposite, there is 3 sequential filters, isn't it?

Comment: Andrew, I will try out your answer and come back with the results.

Comment: @SargeBorsch: Unless you're expecting the evaluation of the filters to happen in parallel, it'll always be sequential in some sense even if they were all in "one" expression.

Comment: Andrew: this did exactly what I was hoping for. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewCoonce of course, yes, but you'll have 3 delegates that call each other instead of 1, and method call can add noticeable overhead.

Comment: @SargeBorsch: You may find this interesting, I know I did, but I just ran the numbers and while the single line was quicker with filters set at ALL/ALL/ALL (37 vs 65 ms @ 1M records), the speed differential dropped off when comparing \*/\*/\* (47 vs 53 ms @ 1M records).